# How to configure triggers for specific users in IRSSI

Tags: perl, ubuntu, irc, channel, irssi

I'm not quite understanding the few examples for the `irssi` trigger.pl script, who's docs can be found [here](http://wouter.coekaerts.be/irssi/trigger), on my Ubuntu machine (If that matters for irssi).

I'm trying to:
When a specific user `foo` joins a specific channel `#channel` , say 2 things in separate chat messages.

(Such as foo in message 1, and bar in message 2 as if I hit the enter key if I were typing it)

What I have so far:

`/trigger add -name "channel_join_chat" -publics -channels "#channel" -joins "foo" -command "Foo" -command "bar"`

And I'm not sure how to specify a specific user, as 'foo' is an unknown option to irssi.

Answer (score 1):

I believe this is what you want:

```
/TRIGGER ADD -name "channel_join_chat" -joins -channels "#channel" -masks foo!*@* -command "Foo" -command "bar"
```

`-publics` should be when someone sends a `PRIVMSG` to a channel, so you want `-joins` to replace that for triggering on a `JOIN` (NOTE: it doesn't take a parameter which is why you get `Unknown option: foo`).

`-masks` is used to match users and wants a `nick!ident@host` mask, so to match the nick only, the mask would be `foo!*@*`.